# Sencha Touch 2.0 - How to set scrolling inside a textarea for Mobile Safari?

Tags: mobile, extjs, safari, scroll, textarea

In my mobile safari project, i need to create a message posting feature. it is requires scrolling inside a textarea when lines of texts exceed the max rows of the text area. i couldn't find 'scrollable' property in Ext.field.textarea, any idea how?
Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in touch 2.0.x such that the framework explicitly prevents the scroll action. Supposedly a fix will be in 2.1, though I didn't see that officially, just from a guy on a forum.

Until then, there is kind of a solution for touch1 here http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?180207-TextArea-scroll-on-iOS-not-working that you can port to V2. It basically involves adding an eventlistener to the actual textarea field (not the sencha object) and then calling preventdefault if it's a valid scrollevent.

The full code is at that link, but the salient bits are here.

Grab the <textarea> field (not the Sencha Touch object) directly and use addListener to apply 
'handleTouch' on touchstart and 'handleMove' on touchmove

```
handleTouch: function(e) { 
  this.lastY = e.pageY;
},

handleMove: function(e) {
  var textArea = e.target;
  var top = textArea.scrollTop <= 0;
  var bottom = textArea.scrollTop + textArea.clientHeight >= textArea.scrollHeight;
  var up = e.pageY > this.lastY;
  var down = e.pageY < this.lastY;

  this.lastY = e.pageY;

  // default (mobile safari) action when dragging past the top or bottom of a scrollable
  // textarea is to scroll the containing div, so prevent that.
  if((top && up) || (bottom && down)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation(); // this tops scroll going to parent
  }

  // Sencha disables textarea scrolling on iOS by default,
  // so stop propagating the event to delegate to iOS.
  if(!(top && bottom)) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // this tops scroll going to parent
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Ext.define('Aspen.util.TextArea', {
override: 'Ext.form.TextArea',
adjustHeight: Ext.Function.createBuffered(function (textarea) {
    var textAreaEl = textarea.getComponent().input;
    if (textAreaEl) {
        textAreaEl.dom.style.height = 'auto';
        textAreaEl.dom.style.height = textAreaEl.dom.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
}, 200, this),

constructor: function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    this.on({
        scope: this,
        keyup: function (textarea) {
            textarea.adjustHeight(textarea);
        },
        change: function (textarea, newValue) {
            textarea.adjustHeight(textarea);
        }
    });
}
```

});